# how can i check if an existing node in firebase using angularfire2?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, angularfire2

im checking to see if a node exists in firebase if my function returns false
i use the push method if true i will use the update method.
this is my function it takes the id:

```
checkIfExist(path:string){
    var a;
    const user = this.db.object(`/users/${path}/`,{ preserveSnapshot: true });
    user.subscribe((obj) => {
      if (obj.$exists()) {
        a  = true;
      } else {
       a = false;
      }
    });
    return a;
  }
```

the first time i push the button it creates a new node even if the node exists
the second time i push the button it updates the node correctly.
why is this happening
every time i refresh the page and i push the save button it creates a new node
but the second time it updates perfectly.

## AskFirebase

Comment: When you subscribe to a collection it will take some time to get result. Better you perform push method and `.exists()` inside your subscription rather than waiting  for a function to get result.

Comment: can you elaborate plz with some examples?

Comment: show your code which runs when you push the button or the function writing to firebase.

Comment: saveData(){


  
  if(this.db.checkIfExist('-Kuim6bKo1CA39uriwZz465')==true){
   console.log("mawjoude");
   this.db.updatingUserInfo(data);
  
  }else{
   this.db.addingUserInfo(data);
   
 }
  
} button method

Comment: addingUserInfo(userInfo:any){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    this.users$.push(userInfo);
    
  }
  updatingUserInfo(userInfo:any){

    this.users$.update('/--Kuim6bKo1CA39uriwZz465/',userInfo).then(_ => console.log('update!'));
    
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
saveData(){
    this.db.object(`/users/YourPath/`,{ preserveSnapshot: true })
        .subscribe(snapshot => {
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
               //data already there, here goes your update method
            }else{
               //no data exists, here goes your push method
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: it didnt work its entering the conditional blocks but no data is being updated or pushed to firebase

Comment: just one quick question why is this .exists() not included in the docs?

Comment: its there in firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists)

Comment: this method is making an infinite loop do you have any other suggestion

Comment: what you mean by 'infinite loop'?

Comment: its always subscribing and my website freezes